# Cannot login to a dockerized mongodb from host, yet still can from the docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am new to Docker and am fighting with this in vain for quite sometime now. After launching mongod from inside a Docker container I can only login to that mongod instance FROM INSIDE THE DOCKER IMAGE, and not from another machine (e.g. host or another machine). Can someone help me ?

```
docker run --name mongo_test -v /db/mongo/test:/data/db -p 127.0.0.1:27019:27019 -d mongo --auth --port 27019
```

Imagine that now my docker image mongo_test has an IP of `172.17.0.2`, I proceed:

```
docker exec -it mongo_test mongo admin --port 27019
db.createUser({ user: 'admin', pwd: 'my_admin_password', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });
exit

docker exec -it mongo_test mongo admin -u admin -p 'my_admin_password' --port 27019
use test_db
db.createUser({ user: 'dev', pwd: 'dev', roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "test_db" }, { role: "readWrite", db: "test_db" } ] });
exit
```

Following is OK

```
docker exec -it mongo_test mongo test_db -u dev -p dev --port 27019
```

Following is NOT OK: with

> Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName:
>   "AuthenticationFailed" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27019 -u dev -p dev --authenticationDatabase test_db
```

This also does not work

```
mongo --host 172.17.0.2 --port 27019 -u dev -p dev --authenticationDatabase test_db
```

---

To further debug, here are the result

```
ps -ax | grep 'mongo'
23969 ?        SLsl   0:06 mongod --auth --port 27019 --bind_ip_all

ps -ax | grep 'docker
23749 ?        Ssl   19:27 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
23760 ?        Ssl   47:21 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
23931 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 27019 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 27019
23952 ?        Sl     0:00 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/8590ce0b6898719ea5a29f1f955f7fda8c6583bfcf6222fd73071446a5177ecc -address /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                 NAMES
xxxxxxxxxxxx        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27019->27019/tcp   mongo_dev
```

Comment: What does docker ps say?

Comment: Please see my update, last part. Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like, for whatever reason, the mongo container is listening on port 2017 on localhost.

Comment: @RobertMoskal: is that because of the "27017/tcp" in the PORTS section ?